# inheritance - use parent's read method in child

Tags: c++, inheritance, ifstream

Can I use parent's `read()` function to read the first and last names, and then have child's `read()` read only the middle name? Or I have to read first, second, and middle in the child?

EDIT:The first answer seems to be working but when I read in child using `strtok`, I get the whole line, not just the third field. Is there a way around it, or I just have to read first two fields into dummy variables and then read third field?

```
class Parent
{
protected:
  char first[80], last[80];

  virtual istream& read(istream &is) {
    char temp[80];
    char *f, *l;
    is >> temp;
    f = strtok(temp, ",");
    strcpy(first, f);
    l = strtok(NULL, ",");
    strcpy(last, l);
    return is;
  }

public:
  friend istream& operator>> (istream &is, Parent &parent) {
    return parent.read(is);
  }
};

class Child: public Parent
{
  char middle[80];

  istream& read(istream &is) {
    /*inherit first and last from parent*/
    char temp[80];
    char *m;
    is >> temp;
    m = strtok(temp, ",");
    strcpy(middle, m);
  }
};

in main()

Parent *object;
ifstream inf("filename.csv");
object = new Child();
inf >> *object;
```

#### cat filename.csv

```
George,Bush,Walker
```

Answer (score 4):

In the `read` function in the child class, you can call the parents `read` function like this:

```
class Child : public Parent
{
    // ...

    std::istream &read(std::istream &is)
    {
        Parent::read(is);
        // Read some more
    }
};
```

Comment: It seems to be working, but when I do is >> temp; cout << temp;, it prints the entire line instead of just last field. Is it normal and I just have to ignore it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the Parent's read function from Child, because `Parent::read()` consumes the complete input (you can only do strtok() without NULL-ptr on a string once, because it actually replaces the delimiter).  The tricky part is that Child has to get information from the middle of the stream.

You could reuse Parent's functions if you declare a `readName()` function, but this doesn't work easily with `strtok()`.  I would propose using an `std::istringstream` for this where you enter the line (instead of using strtok) and pass to `readName()` as parameter.  With strtok(), you could do a prepareRead() where you do the tokenizing and then read in the readName() function with strtok(NULL,","), but that depends heavily on side-effects inside functions.

Not compiled/tested/handled error-cases, so don't copy/paste this for your assignment:

```
class Parent {
protected:
  std::string first, last;
  std::istringstream readLine(istream& is)
  {
    std::string line;
    std::getline(is, line);
    return std::istringstream(line);
  }
  std::string readName(std::istringstream& iss)
  {
    std::string name;
    std::getline(iss, name, ',');
    return name;
  }

  virtual istream& read(istream &is) 
  {
    std::istringstream iss = readLine(is);
    first = readFirstName(iss);
    last = readLastName(iss);
    return is;
  }
public:
  friend istream& operator>> (istream &is, Parent &parent) 
  {
    return parent.read(is);
  }
};

class Child : public Parent
{
private:
  std::string middle;
  virtual istream& read(istream &is) 
  {
    std::istringstream iss = readLine(is);
    first = readName(iss);
    middle = readName(iss)
    last = readName(iss);
    return is;
  }
};
```

Remark that you should avoid strcpy, especially with input: you're program will fail and can be hacked by passing a file containing names larger than 80 characters, which can be avoided by using std::string and std::istringstream.

Answer (score 0):

1) Don't declare the parent method as `virtual` and change the following code:

```
class Child: public Parent {
    char middle[80];
    istream& read(istream &is) {
    Parent::read(is);
    char temp[80];
    char *m;
    is >> temp;
    m = strtok(temp, ",");
    strcpy(middle, m); }
};
```

Without using `virtual`... parent method will be hidden.

*Edit: thanks for [cppcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/806299/cppcoder) attention. this was wrong. see the next approach.*

2) Or use `using` declaration, This is an example from C++ standard:

```
struct A {
    virtual void f();
};

struct B : virtual A {
    virtual void f();
};

struct C : B , virtual A {
    using A::f;
};

void foo() {
    C c;
    c.f(); // calls B::f, the final overrider
    c.C::f(); // calls A::f because of the using-declaration
}
```

Comment: I don't think, having parent method as virtual give any issue.

Comment: @cppcoder: I did c++ programming one years ago! but i remember that.

Comment: It's a homework, I forgot to put the tag, and parent function must be virtual. Still, istream is gives me the whole line, not just third field. How do I go about it?

Comment: @ccSadegh Since the parent method is invoked using the scope resolution operator, `virtual` keyword does not come into play there. Just try it out.

Comment: I don't want to start another question just for this. Why would is return a whole line instead of just last field? What am I missing?